# Forcing Dovecot 2.3.4.1 to use TLSv1.2

Tags: email, ssl, dovecot, openssl, ios

Since the new Debian Buster update, I have some issue with TLSv1.3.

Issue: my iOS mail client could not connect to my mail server (12.2) and I do not want to upgrade right now, so I try to find a way to disable TLSv1.3 with dovecot.

The current versions are: OpenSSL 1.1.1c and Dovecot 2.3.4.1

In Dovecot 2.3 the SSL settings are changed from ssl_protocols to ssl_min_protocol.

```
# Minimum SSL protocol version to use. Potentially recognized values are SSLv3,
# TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2, depending on the OpenSSL version used.
```

But I would like to force Dovecot to use TLSv1.2 instead of using a minumum SSL protocol, because Dovecot will try before the highest SSL protocol available first (TLSv1.3). If I set TLSv1.3 it will not use TLSv1.2.

So, anyone known how to force Dovecot 2.3.4.1 to use TLSv1.2?

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, but maybe part of a solution:

1. I tried the solution suggested by @joffrey, but could not get it to
work. Enabling or disabling TLSv1.3 ciphersuites in `ssl_cipher_list`
seems to be completely ignored by Dovecot 2.3.4.1. The
`ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` does not have any effect on TLSv1.3 either.
No matter what Dovecot settings I tried, I was unable to prevent a
client from negotiating TLSv1.3 and choosing any TLSv1.3 ciphersuite it
wanted.

This is probably related to the introduction in OpenSSL 1.1.1 of a new
method for selecting TLSv1.3 ciphersuites, in addition to the already
existing method for selecting ciphers for TLSv1.2 and below. The
OpenSSL developers were aware of the inconvenience this would cause,
but said it was unavoidable, see
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/5392. Dovecot commit
[8f6f04eb](https://github.com/dovecot/core/commit/8f6f04eb21276f28b81695dd0d3df57c7b8f43e4)
seems to lay the groundwork for a new Dovecot option probably to be
named `ssl_ciphersuites` as a front-end to the new OpenSSL method for
TLSv1.3, also in addition to the existing `ssl_cipher_list` for TLSv1.2
and below. This commit was first included in Dovecot 2.3.9, but that
version has not been packaged for Debian yet. Also, I do not see the
option mentioned in the Dovecot
[NEWS](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/2.3.9.3/NEWS) or online
documentation, so maybe they are not finished yet.

2. Alternatively, I found that adding `MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2` to
`/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` works (***warning***: this will change the
behaviour of many other programs using OpenSSL as well!):

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

This immediately prevents Dovecot 2.3.4.1 from negotiating TLSv1.3. No
need to even restart it. But, as warned above, this solution also
affects other applications, not just Dovecot, so is of limited use.

In an attempt to target the settings to Dovecot exclusively, I tried
setting an environment variable to point to a specific config file:

```
# OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/openssl-max-tlsv12.cnf dovecot -F
```

But that did not have any effect on Dovecot. I checked that the
variable was visible in the environment and that it worked for other
OpenSSL applications. However, I suspect that the OpenSSL library
itself does not look at environment variables and that it is considered
the responsibility of the calling program (Dovecot) to somehow pass the
content of the variable to the library. I doubt that Dovecot does this,
because I do not see any use of the OpenSSL CONF library in the Dovecot
source code. I also could not get a dovecot application section in the
OpenSSL config file to work, nor did I find any Dovecot options for
setting an OpenSSL config file location or the application section name
to be used from the OpenSSL config file. Perhaps someone else knows how
to target OpenSSL settings to a specific program instead of
system-wide?

3. Finally, you could always try to edit source code, of course. For
the current Debian dovecot package, you could start by duplicating
[this
line](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dovecot/-/blob/debian/1%252.3.4.1-5+deb10u1/src/lib-ssl-iostream/iostream-openssl-context.c#L402),
change `SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version` to 
`SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version` and then recompile. I did not really
want to go that far myself. You might as well just start using
upstream directly instead of the distribution package then.

Comment: Good question and answer -- which pointed me in the right direction. There was another change approximately 10/1/21 in updates to `openssl 1.1.1.l-1` and `dovecot 2.3.16-1` that killed the ability of older iPhone mail from connecting to the mail server. I don't know whether dovecot improved the `ssl_min_protocol` option in `10-ssl.conf`, but adding `ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1` and using all other default values allowed connection again. This solved my `"SSL_accept() failed: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol"` error.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to locate the 10-ssl.conf file (usually in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/).

Edit and go to line that contains *ssl_protocols* (mine is line 52).
In that line you can also deny protocols. You can try

```
ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2 !TLSv1.3
```

Comment: The ssl_protocols configuration parameter was removed in 2.3 (https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Upgrading/2.3)

Comment: That's what I used with previous Dovecot version, but the latest do not use anymore this variable, now it's ssl_min_protocol =

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed i'm using an earlier version of dovecot

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried or reproduced but you could try to set the [ssl_min_protol](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/master/doc/example-config/conf.d/10-ssl.conf) to TLSv1.2 and define [ssl_cipher_list](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/master/doc/example-config/conf.d/10-ssl.conf) to not include any [specific TLS1.3 ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#TLS-v1.3-cipher-suites).

Comment: I will try this, thank you, but I do not know what should be my ssl_cipher_list ?

Right know, it's the default one:

ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH

Comment: You could search the internet for a cipher list which does not contain the 'ALL' group, and does not contain ciphers which are in the TLSv1.3 cipher list. This is kind of tricky because all examples would recommend using TLSv1.3. I'm not giving a specific example because I would not like to be responsible for configuring your security. A list of ciphers should be chosen with care and responsibility of maintaining a proper list with 'un-broken' ciphers over time is paramount to a good security policy.

Comment: Will try to found out the solution with cypher list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this configuration snippet, placed in local.conf, or conf.d/10-ssl.conf

```
# doveconf -n | grep -iE "tls|ssl"
ssl = required
ssl_ca = </path/to/ca/bundle.pem
ssl_cert = </path/to/cert.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!RSA:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384:!LOW@STRENGTH
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
```